# McAfee scan exclude webdirectory

Tags: anti-virus

I'm scanning my web page using McAfee. I'm getting secure alert from phpMyAdmin  documentation folder. I believe that not necessary to scan phpMyAdmin folder.

Q1: How can I exclude this directory from scan?

Q2: Why is the McAfee scan certificate is not displayed in my webpage footer?

Comment: What do you mean your McAfee scan certificate is not being displayed?  You need to modify your website to include that image.

Comment: @Ramhound: Im not sure. images.scanalert.com/meter/xxx.com/13.gif this is the image source we used. I think because of the error the image is not loading.